# Constructing a differential equation from germs

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

For two given germs of the functions $f(z), g(z)$, how to construct a differential equation with solutions of the form
$$y(z)=\frac{a\,f(z)+b\,g(z)}{c\,f(z)+d\,g(z)}$$
where $a, b, c, d$ are arbitrary complex numbers?

Edit 1: This is the third part of a problem in my ODE class, but I don't know what knowledge I should use to solve this problem. Other parts of the problem are the followings:

For a differential equation with meromorphic coefficients of the form
$$y’’+ p(z) y’ + q(z) y = 0$$
a.Find the substitution $y = ψ\widetilde{y}$ that reduces the equation to
$$\widetilde{y}’’ + Q(z) \widetilde{y} = 0$$
Where is this replacement defined?

b.Build a differential equation that everyone satisfies functions of the form $y_1 / y_2$, where $y_1, y_2$ are any two nonzero solutions of the equation of the original equation.

Edit 2: Does this have something to do with Möbius transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a), just insert the product derivatives 
$$
0=[ψ\tilde y''+2ψ'\tilde y'+ψ''\tilde y]+p[ψ\tilde y'+ψ'\tilde y]+qψ\tilde y
\\
=ψ\tilde y'' + [2ψ'+pψ]\tilde y'+[ψ''+pψ'+qψ]\tilde y
$$
so that for the desired normal form you need to solve the first order equation $0=2ψ'+pψ$, $ψ=\exp(-\frac12\int p(z)dz)$.

For b) I take it that you were asking the original question as a method to solve this? If $y_2=ψy_1$, then from the same formula as above it follows that
$$
0=ψ''y_1+[2y_1'+py_1]ψ'
$$
Now take the derivative and insert the original ODE
$$
0=ψ'''y_1+ψ''y_1'+[2y_1'+py_1]ψ''
      +[\underbrace{-2py_1'-2qy_1}_{=2y_1''}+py_1'+p'y_1]ψ'
$$
This now gives a homogeneous linear system in $y_1$ and $y_1'$,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
ψ''+pψ'&2ψ'\\ψ'''+pψ''+[p'-2q]ψ'&3ψ''-pψ'
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\y_1'
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
As $y_1$ is non-zero, the determinant of the coefficient matrix has to be zero. This gives a differential equation in the quotient $ψ=\frac{y_2}{y_1}$ only.

Answer (score 1):

How about something bone-headed like this:
$$y'(z)=\frac{(c\,f(z)+d\,g(z))(a\,f'(z)+b\,g'(z))-(a\,f(z)+b\,g(z))(c\,f'(z)+d\,g'(z))}{(c\,f(z)+d\,g(z))^2}? $$
Although why you would need to do that is not clear. Maybe you could type up a little more context?